# How to define generics return in an interface?

Tags: java, generics

My implementation looks like this.

```
@Override
public <T extends AlgorithmSuperType> T doSomethingSmart(){
    //do this and that
}
```

How could I define the interface for this generic return value? Eclipse recommends this interface definition.

```
T doSomethingSmart();
```

When I accept the quick fix, Eclipse finds fault with it and recommends to prepend `<T>`.

```
<T> T doSomethingSmart();
```

None of these quick fixes of the interface resolve the conflict in the @Override implementation.

Any clue how to properly define the interface?

Comment: *"How could I define the interface for this generic return value?"* What do you mean by "interface"?

Comment: Can you provide more information such as the context which the implementation will be used?

Comment: A method with signature `<T extends AlgorithmSuperType> T doSomethingSmart();` is almost certainly wrong, because it means a function that can return a type that it doesn't even (and can't) know. So it needs to be able to return every possible type, at the same time. However, unless it returns `null`, this is impossible, because the return value can only be a specific type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `T` is a generic parameter, you need to declare it as a parameter, by making either the method or your class to be generic. Eclipse is suggesting the first alternative. Here's how to do the second:

```
public class<T extends AlgorithmSuperType> MyClass implements SomeInterface<T> {
    @Override
    public T doSomethingSmart(){
        //do this and that
    }
}
```

Note that the interface should be either

```
public interface<T extends AlgorithmSuperType> SomeInterface {
    T doSomethingSmart();
}
```

or

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    <T extends AlgorithmSuperType> T doSomethingSmart();
}
```

(In the latter, case, `MyClass` should be "implements SomeInterface" rather than `implements SomeInterface<T>`.

Comment: You are right. I missed the <T> after "implements". No compilation error. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

The interface would look something like this:

```
interface YourInterfaceName {
    <T extends AlgorithmSuperType> T doSomethingSmart();
}
```

That defines an interface with a generic *method*, which is what your implementation defines.

Answer (score 0):

If it's interface then you could use:

AlgorithmSuperType  fetchAlert();

But all other classes inheriting from this type will also be ok, not justT.